# How to create AWS nodejs lambda function with dependency

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, dependencies, zip

I have a very basic node.js example running AWS and I need to modify the code to add a dependency on the "request" module.

I have understood that you need to package this up into a zip file with the necessary node module.

I download the index.js and add the code.  I create package.json:

`{
      "name": "function",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "index.js",
      "scripts": {
        "zip": "zip function.zip package.json *.js node_modules"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "aws-sdk": "^2.4.10",
        "request": "^1.0"
      }
    }`

I use npm install to pull in the dependency.  This populated the node_modules subfolder with the module and its dependencies.

Then I just zipped this up but the AWS console would not upload it.

This Q&A [Creating a lambda function in AWS from zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30670957/creating-a-lambda-function-in-aws-from-zip-file) told me *not* to zip normally but to use npm like so:
`    npm run zip

```
> function@1.0.0 zip /Users/paul_tanner/Desktop/index
> zip function.zip package.json *.js node_modules

  adding: package.json (deflated 36%)
  adding: index.js (deflated 73%)
  adding: node_modules/ (stored 0%)`
```

Before trying to upload and test this I opened it up to check that the dependencies were included.  They were not.

Just for the hell of it I also tried uploading the resulting "function.zip".  Again, AWS Lambda would not upload it.

So the question is how should one create and upload an AWS Lambda function with dependency?

Answer (score 0):

The Linux zip utility has worked fine for me,
Looking at the output of the zip command that you show, I think the only bit you are missing is the recursive option (-r). Try this:

```
# zip -r function.zip package.json *.js node_modules
```

If the file is too big, you cannot upload it directly, in such cases use S3 to store you packaged function and finally load it into Lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to "statically" link all of the modules into one big `.js` file and upload that.

This questions describes how: [Packaging code for AWS Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47905321/packaging-code-for-aws-lambda)