# How to structure AWS Lambda ZIP file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, terraform

I have a simple lambda consisting of `index.js` and `node_modules`. When I zip these two files (either by zipping both directly or by zipping the parent directory), it places them inside a folder which is then zipped.

I then upload this zip to my S3 bucket which works fine.

My Lambda however, can't find the right files because it seems to have nested the `index.js` handler inside an extra directory (I assume this happens from the zipping)

[image]

I am using Terraform to create my Lambda function which references the S3 bucket:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "Lambda" {
  s3_bucket     = var.bucket_id
  s3_key        = "on-sign-in-trigger.zip"
  handler       = "index.handler"
  runtime       = "nodejs18.x"
  role          = aws_iam_role.lambda_iam_role.arn
  function_name = "on-sign-in-trigger-${var.env_name}"
}
```

Do I need to configure Lambda so that it knows to go a folder deeper to get the handler function or is there another way I should be zipping / uploading my code to S3?

Comment: I believe the handler has to be in the root of the zip file, not in a folder. You seem unclear on what is actually happening in your zip file. At a minimum you should open the zip file and look at the contents to verify how it is structured. That is a minimum level of debugging you should do before anyone can really help you.

Comment: This answer is what you are looking for:) [Creating a lambda function in AWS from zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38623471/12326605)

Comment: Thanks @MarkB, as I mentioned in my post, when I zip the files, it places them inside a folder. My question was is there another way to zip them to avoid it getting nested or if I can update my lamdba config. Looks like I've found the answer though. Cheers

Comment: You said "I assume this happens from the zipping" which made it unclear what you were actually sure of.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I needed to add the folder path to my handler value:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "Lambda" {
  s3_bucket     = var.bucket_id
  s3_key        = "on-sign-in-trigger.zip"
  handler       = "on-sign-in-trigger/index.handler" // add directory path here
  runtime       = "nodejs18.x"
  role          = aws_iam_role.lambda_iam_role.arn
  function_name = "on-sign-in-trigger-${var.env_name}"
}
```

I guess `on-sign-in-trigger/index.handler` is the path the lambda looks for inside the zipped file